# Makefile always executes even though it shouldn't

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

makefile noob here, my makefile always executes every recipe even though the files are up to date. Here is my code:

```
vpath *.pdf ../../../Figures/Arrowshape/ChemicalNoise

  .PHONY : all clean

all : Fig_VP-CN-Revols_MeanfromDist_Dac0.0_F0.0-4.0_0to2.pdf\
  Fig_VP-CN-Revols_MeanfromDist_Dac0.0_F0.0-4.0_2to4.pdf\
  Fig_VP-CN-Revols_MeanfromDistImshow_Dac0.0_F0.0-4.0.pdf

Fig_%.pdf : %.py
  $(warning Building $@ )
  python $<

Fig_%_2to4.pdf : %.py
   $(warning Building $@ )
   python $<

Fig_%_0to2.pdf : %.py
  $(warning Building $@ )
    python $<

  clean:
    rm all
```

I checked that the pdf files are put in the correct folder and the names match. What is wrong with my syntax? 
Also, I know that my `clean` does not work, how would I make it work though?

Comment: For the clean part of the question, it would be `clean :` (newline/tab) `rm $(all)`   (`all` is a variable in this case.  What you had would try and remove a file with the literal name `all`)

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. It seems to have the variable `all` empty. Are you sure `all` is treated as variable?

Comment: Sorry, my bad -- (For some reason I thought you had `all := ` instead of `all :` -- that being said, that would be the way to go about this -- create a variable `ALL_DEPS := ...`, and then do `rm -f $(ALL_DEPS )` in your clean recipe and use `all : $(ALL_DEPS )`. for your main rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "put in the correct folder", which folder is that?

It's clearly not the local directory, because if it were your makefile would work.

The first thing wrong is you have the wrong syntax for `vpath`.  See the manual; `vpath` takes a makefile pattern (that is a string with zero or one `%` character); it doesn't support shell globbing like `*.h`.  This should be written:

```
vpath %.pdf ../../../Figures/Arrowshape/ChemicalNoise
```

However, even with that fix your makefile won't work as you hope, because `vpath` is not intended to find *targets*.  It's intended to find *source files* (that is, files that are not created by make).

If you want to understand this deeply you can read http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/

To get your makefile to work as you want you'll have to add in paths, like this:

```
OUTDIR = ../../../Figures/Arrowshape/ChemicalNoise

all : $(OUTDIR)/Fig_VP-CN-Revols_MeanfromDist_Dac0.0_F0.0-4.0_0to2.pdf\
      $(OUTDIR)/Fig_VP-CN-Revols_MeanfromDist_Dac0.0_F0.0-4.0_2to4.pdf\
      $(OUTDIR)/Fig_VP-CN-Revols_MeanfromDistImshow_Dac0.0_F0.0-4.0.pdf

$(OUTDIR)/Fig_%.pdf : %.py
        $(warning Building $@ )
        python $<

$(OUTDIR)/Fig_%_2to4.pdf : %.py
        $(warning Building $@ )
        python $<

$(OUTDIR)/Fig_%_0to2.pdf : %.py
        $(warning Building $@ )
        python $<
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. By correct folder I meant the location I gave vpath corresponds to the location the pdf files are generated by the python script. Do you happen to know a solution for the rm all issue in my clean?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You haven't said what you want it to do.  If you want it to delete the files that were created you have to list those files in the `rm` command.  Also you should use `rm -f` so it doesn't fail if they don't exist.

Comment: Yes, clean is supposed to delete the target files from `all`. `rm -f` is a good hint, thanks.

Comment: Well, `rm all` deletes the file called `all`.  If you want to delete the target files you have to list them; remember that make basically invokes shell commands (after expanding make variables/functions) so whatever command you'd enter into the shell to delete the files is what you'd enter into the makefile recipe.